# Java import jar file: package func does not exist

Tags: java

My worktree

```
.
├── func
│   ├── Func.class
│   └── Func.java
└── hello
    ├── Main.class
    └── Main.java
```

func/Func.java

```
package func;

public class Func {
    public static void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

hello/Main.java

```
package hello;

import func.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Func.hello();
    }
}
```

I used `javac` to compile `Func.java` and `Main.java`, and this worked.
 Then I `jar cvf classes.jar func/Func.class`, put the jar file into my CLASSPATH and removed the func directory. After that, when I tried to run `javac hello/Main.java`, it reported

```
hello/Main.java:3: error: package func does not exist
import func.*;
^
hello/Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Func.hello();
        ^
  symbol:   variable Func
  location: class Main
2 errors
```

I can't find out what is wrong with it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... when I tried to run `javac hello/Main.java`, it reported ...

You need to add the JAR file containing the `func` classes to the compile time classpath:

```
  javac -classpath classes.jar hello/Main.java
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Is the compile time classpath different with what I set as the environment variable `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: No it isn't different.  But setting the classpath using -classpath is cleaner.  (And clearly, you didn't have classes.jar in your $CLASSPATH when you tried to compile the `Main` class.)  I recommend that you read 1) The Oracle Java Tutorial "Getting Started" section and 2) the manual entry for the `java` and `javac` commands ... paying attention to the parts that explain the classpath and how to set it.